# How to stop infinite loop in bxslider?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I use ultimate auction plugin on wordpress for listing my auctions and if I add more then one picture of product, the slider automatically go to the next picture and never stop. I want to manually go to the next picture. Which settings I must change?

In minified js file, infiniteLoop=!1 and autoStart=!1 and still have an infinite loop.
Bellow are my settings:

```
var defaults = {

  // GENERAL
  mode: 'horizontal',
  slideSelector: '',
  infiniteLoop: false,
  hideControlOnEnd: false,
  speed: 500,
  easing: null,
  slideMargin: 0,
  startSlide: 0,
  randomStart: false,
  captions: false,
  ticker: false,
  tickerHover: false,
  adaptiveHeight: false,
  adaptiveHeightSpeed: 500,
  video: false,
  useCSS: true,
  preloadImages: 'visible',
  responsive: true,
  slideZIndex: 50,
  wrapperClass: 'bx-wrapper',

  // TOUCH
  touchEnabled: true,
  swipeThreshold: 50,
  oneToOneTouch: true,
  preventDefaultSwipeX: true,
  preventDefaultSwipeY: false,

  // ACCESSIBILITY
  ariaLive: true,
  ariaHidden: true,

  // KEYBOARD
  keyboardEnabled: false,

  // PAGER
  pager: true,
  pagerType: 'full',
  pagerShortSeparator: ' / ',
  pagerSelector: null,
  buildPager: null,
  pagerCustom: null,

  // CONTROLS
  controls: true,
  nextText: 'Next',
  prevText: 'Prev',
  nextSelector: null,
  prevSelector: null,
  autoControls: false,
  startText: 'Start',
  stopText: 'Stop',
  autoControlsCombine: false,
  autoControlsSelector: null,

  // AUTO
  auto: false,
  pause: 4000,
  autoStart: false,
  autoDirection: 'next',
  stopAutoOnClick: false,
  autoHover: false,
  autoDelay: 0,
  autoSlideForOnePage: false,

  // CAROUSEL
  minSlides: 1,
  maxSlides: 1,
  moveSlides: 0,
  slideWidth: 0,
  shrinkItems: false,
```

Comment: where is the slider initialized? Even if you change it in the defaults area of the minified JS, these can be overridden by the init params. Please attach that code so we can have a look

Comment: @cornel.raiu Folosesc ultimate auction si este initializat cand adaug imaginile produsului. Ma chinui de multa vreme cu chestia asta. Mai multe nu-ti pot spune ca nu stiu jquery.

Comment: let's discuss it in English so that others can also benefit from this. Maybe if you attach a link to the problem I can have a quick look.

Comment: Link to the page [link](https://licitatii.columbodrombradu.ro/licitare/ro-18-089854-m/)

Comment: if you go here: view-source:http://licitatii.columbodrombradu.ro/licitare/ro-18-089854-m/ you will see on lines 345-354 that the carousel is being initialized in and it does not have the `auto: false` setting as it is required to not autoplay. Maybe you can check and see in the carousel plugin you are using maybe there is a setting.

Comment: checking their free plugin and see if I can put up a fix for this from that code

Comment: the bxslider is a folder in ultimate auction plugin. I must check the page where auctions are listed.

Comment: I use the paid version of the plugin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199281/discussion-between-cornel-raiu-and-alex).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the developers of the `ultimate-auction-pro` plugin did not do this configurable.

Also, they are not using the bxSlider but the standard BootStrap carousel: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#carousel

But, you can adjust this by overriding the template file in your child theme.

So, you have to do the following:

In the child theme, create the file `ultimate-auction-template.php`. Copy the whole content of the file with the same name from the plugin folder. Then, inn the file you will find the init code for the carousel

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000
});
```

According to the documentaion, you will have to replace this with

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false
})
```

Then everything should work. Let me know if that helped :)

Comment: please explain why you downvoted this :) read the comments and see that my answer is exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 0):

bxslider have built in method `auto` . When you initialize your slider you need to set that `false`.

See the example below. Slider is not rotated automatically. You need to click to change image.

```js
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: false
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css" media="screen" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <li><img src="https://nagariknews.nagariknetwork.com/media/cache/nagarik_thumbnail_996_491/uploads/media/2019/September/myar_Shakya_Indrajatra.jpg" title="<h3>test4321</h3>"></li>
    <li><img src="https://nagariknews.nagariknetwork.com/media/cache/nagarik_thumbnail_996_491/uploads/media/2019/September/Migrant%20workers%20leaving%20home%20ktm.jpg" title="<h3>Test123</h3>"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```